# How to read single column of xlsx file into a dataframe?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlsx

I have an .xlsx file with 5 sheets, each sheet has 4 columns and I need to read the first column of the 5th sheet into a column of a dataframe.

I've tried this:

`df = read_excel('file_path.xlsx', sheet_names='sheet_5', index_col='column_name'`

However this seems to copy the whole sheet into the dataframe rather than just the first column.

Comment: There's an `usecols` option in `read_excel`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@Quang Hoang's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4238408/quang-hoang) comment, I found the solution.

```
df = pd.read_excel('file_path.xlsx', sheet_name, usecols=['column_name'])
```

The `usecols` option in `read_excel` only read in the column I wanted into the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Hey lets try it this way.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv ('path/to/file.csv', sheet_name = '5', index_col = 0)
print(df[['column_name']])
```

Tell me if it works, I recommend you reading documentation

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html